# Switch color defined in LESS base on scala variable - switch color theme in different environment

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, less

I am trying to use different color theme in my 3 environments: dev (green), uat(blue) and prod(red).

I would like to know if, I can read the environment variable in scala in global.scala

```
override def onStart(app: Application) {
  val env = System.getenv("SYSTEM_ENV")    //{DEV|UAT|PRD}
}
```

And then do something on the LESS file that I have, myTheme.LESS

```
@basecolor: #3B6A52;
```

which will be read from my other CSS/LESS file as the base background base color

Can I have some logic here to determine the color from my scala variable?
e.g. if dev then green else if ....etc

Or if I can have 3 mytheme files, e.g. mythemeRed.LESS, mytmemeBlue.LESS could be determined by play to read only one of them.

Please shed me some light and any idea is welcome.

Comment: Have you tried just doing a match statement where you define the css? This would work easily for multiple css files. Just match the env variable and do something like `case "DEV" => "devstyle.css"`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to mix javascript and LESS in that way. I would just do something like:

```
if (env === "DEV"){
    var styleRef = document.createElement("link");
    styleRef.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    styleRef.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    styleRef.setAttribute("href", "dev-style.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleRef);
}
else if (env === "UAT"){
...
}
```

And so on. You can then fetch the correct compiled CSS file according to your environment.